# Lazy video loading view in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uitableview

in my Application list of video (using TableView Custom cell each cell contain video view) that automatically play when cell is visible to screen (just like vine video list view) i done that and its working fine.

i have programmed that when when scroll is visible then video object create and play that automatically then if cell is not visible than i stop that video and remove that object.

now what i want my tableview list not scrolling smoothly like vine video listing. ( my list view stuck for half and second when video object is created on  cell visible)

Comment: using SDWebImage or AFNetworking You can do Lazy loading very smoothly

Comment: Do you start playing the video after the scroll view stops decelerating/user ends dragging? or whenever it becomes visible

Comment: @EdLess  i am doing exactly that way . all working fine but just stuck when cell is visible because of movie player object is created.

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya Can you post some code...

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @AlexTau done same as lazy Loding image